# Do the character interactions have any effect on the game?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

While playing the bureau you can interact with characters in different ways. For example there is the side quest where you can talk to the comms officer about the radio transmission. During this interaction you seem to make a choice, or at least suggest a choice to the comms officer. (About how she deals with the survivors).

Later the same sort of interaction occurs with DaSilva, you can tell him to sacrifice himself, or tell him that you will try to find a cure for his infection. I chose the latter. So he turned up in my base as one of the infected.

Now I was wondering, do these conversation options always have the same effect? Do the options have cosmetic effects? As in, there are different people in the base between missions. Does it influence the ending? Or is it just fleshing out of the world?

I know some of them unlock side missions, and others unlock new items. But those have a clear effect so I'm not wondering about those.

Comment: I'm wondering the same. I just told DeSilva, that he should not sacrifice himself. If you told him the opposite and I'm through with the game, we could compare the results and maybe have an answer.

Comment: @Sentry Soo...?

Comment: @Zommuter Nothing to compare, yet. We both seem to have chosen "not sacrifice"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what effect DaSilva's presence had, but when I let him sacrifice himself (by crashing a car into the gas station next to the tower's entrance) he most certainly died and was gone. I think Angie was rather upset about this, but lacking comparison I guess there's no severe difference...

Comment: Yeah, if he dies he dies of course. :D I was just wondering about any non obvious effects. The DaSilva choice was just meant as an example btw. I was looking for the effect of any choice you make ingame. There are a few more that seem to not have an obvious effect.

For now I'm assuming that they are all just fleshing out the world.

Comment: @Ids I'd say the only major influence is the choice of person towards the end which I don't want to spoil here ;-)